# Alterar cor do título ActionBar

Tags: java, android, sdk, widget

Este é meu novo layout, porém os items do overflow ficaram em branco com fundo branco, e preciso de fundo branco com letras em preto. Lembrando que utilizei o stylegenerator.

```
<style name="Theme.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Datalayer</item>
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Datalayer.Widget</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Datalayer</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Datalayer</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_datalayer</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_datalayer</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_datalayer</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_datalayer</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Datalayer.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Datalayer</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Datalayer</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver o problema por completo, com o uso do [**ActionBar Style Generator**](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator), o **Base Theme** como `Light - Dark Action Bar` e sobreescreva o tema que esta usando. Dessa forma os estilos dos elementos do `ActionBar` ficarão homogêneos e não haverá mais problemas.

Como uma forma de estilizar pontualmente alguns itens, como o ícone do `Overflow Menu` e o estilo do título e sub-título do `ActionBar` recomendo os estilos abaixo.

Para alterar o `drawable` relativo ao `Overflow Menu`, basta acrescentar essa regra de estilo no seu tema:

```
<style name="Theme.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Demais regras omitidas -->

    <!-- SDK 14+ -->
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Theme.Datalayer.OverFlow</item>
    <!-- Se usar alguma impl. de actionbar de compatibilidade. e.g: AppCompat
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Theme.Datalayer.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Datalayer.OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/seu_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Procure gerar os ícones a partir do [Android Asset Studio - Icon Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html) do Roman Nurik ou no fork do [shreyasachar](http://shreyasachar.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html) com ícones atualizados do Material Design.

Para alterar o titulo é mais simples porque já esta redefinindo o estilo do título, basta mudar a cor. Altere o seu `style MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle` assim:

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <!-- Altere a cor abaixo -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_text</item>
    <!-- Altere a cor abaixo, acredito que essa regra nao eh necessaria -->
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/action_bar_text</item>
    <!-- Altere a cor abaixo, acredito que essa regra nao eh necessaria -->
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@color/action_bar_text</item>
</style>
```

Ainda falta alterar a cor do subtítulo, se precisar:
Ai terá que fazer análogamente ao estilo do título:

```
<style name="Theme.Datalayer" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Demais regras omitidas -->
    <!-- Acrescente a regra abaixo -->
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.SubTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Crie este estilo -->
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.SubTitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <!-- Altere a cor abaixo -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_text</item>
    <!-- Altere a cor abaixo, acredito que essa regra nao eh necessaria -->
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/action_bar_text</item>
    <!-- Altere a cor abaixo, acredito que essa regra nao eh necessaria -->
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@color/action_bar_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Está assim porque usei o style generator. Vou tentar suas dicas, muito obrigada

Comment: Acredito que tenha usado esse style generator ( http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), nele tem uma Combobox de `Base Theme`, marque a opção `Light - Dark Action Bar`. Acredito que seja a melhor solução se não for causar problemas.

Comment: Resolveu o título e o verflow, porém meu background do popup é branco, então volto a questão...agora alterar a cor da letra do popup

Comment: Popup seria o `Dialog`? Esse estilo modificou a cor do título do `Dialog`?

Comment: a cor do texto dos itens do overflow

Comment: @Juliana Tentei encontrar o estilo do item dos itens do PopupMenu mas não achei. Recomendo fortemente que gere novamente o seu estilo usando o `DarkActionBar`, assim fica homogêneo o tema. Acho que alterar pontualmente um ou outro não vai resolver o problema por completo.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido! Segue alteração no xml:

@drawable/selectable_background_datalayer
        @style/PopupMenu.Datalayer
        @style/DropDownListView.Datalayer
        @style/ActionBarTabStyle.Datalayer
        @style/DropDownNav.Datalayer
        @style/ActionBar.Solid.Datalayer
        @drawable/cab_background_top_datalayer
        @drawable/cab_background_bottom_datalayer
        @style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Datalayer
        @color/black
        
        @style/Theme.Datalayer.Widget
        @style/TextAppearance

```
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```