# Alterando cor do titulo de uma activity aberta

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbar

Estou tentando alterar a cor do texto da minha Action Bar, mas não estou conseguindo...
Pesquisei aqui e em outros lugares e a resposta é sempre bem parecida como essa resposta:

[Alterando cor do titulo da minha aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37361/alterando-cor-do-titulo-da-minha-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

No entanto, sempre que eu altero, nunca a Action Bar muda a cor do texto... Já consegui diminuir o texto, mudar o fundo... Mas o texto insiste em ficar em branco...

Vou colocar o meu código inteiro aqui para ver se alguém consegue me ajudar, pois não sei se pode esta acontecendo alguma sobreposição de dados:

Código do meu arquivo themes:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorSecondaryText</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Style usado no tema das activitys do manifest. -->
    <style name="Theme.App.BackActionBar" >
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Theme.App.ActionBar.HomeAsUpActionBarStyle</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.App.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.App.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.App.Fullscreen" parent="Theme.App">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Theme.App.ActionBar.Fullscreen
        </item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.FullscreenContainer" parent="">
        <item name="fullscreenBackgroundColor">@color/fullscreenBackgroundColor</item>
        <item name="fullscreenTextColor">@color/fullscreenTextColor</item>
    </style>
```

Código do meu arquivo styles:

```
 <style name="Widget.Theme.App.ActionBar.Fullscreen" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Theme.App.ActionBar.HomeAsUpActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="displayOptions">showTitle|homeAsUp</item>

        <!-- Title Text Color -->
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarSubTitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarSubTitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="background">?attr/colorSecondary</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/red</item>

        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarSubTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/red</item>

        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Theme.App.ButtonBar.Fullscreen" parent="">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Como eu estou adicionando o tema nas activitys no meu manifest:

```
         <activity
            android:name=".TimeActivity"
            android:label="@string/label_TimeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.BackActionBar" />
```

E tem mais.. Se for for dar voto negativo, pelo menos avisa aonde estou errando para eu aprender com os erros, pq eu genuinamente não sei onde estou errando... É a minha segunda pergunta em que os usuários do stack negativam... E ninguém consegue me responder...

E não é como simplesmente eu fizesse uma pergunta gratuita no site…
Como eu disse eu pesquisei! e mesmo implementando essas respostas e outras:

[Mudando cor da ActionBar no Style](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45263/mudando-cor-da-actionbar-no-style)

[Alterar cor do título ActionBar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30699/alterar-cor-do-t%C3%ADtulo-actionbar)

Não obtive nenhum resultado...

Answer (score 0):

Carlos, pelo que vi do seu código parece estar correto (mas não testei localmente).

Você tentou fazer a alteração programaticamente, dessa forma abaixo?

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Programaticamente funciona.... Mas o problema é que deste modo eu não consigo usar o tema noturno